# IntelliJ IDEAでバックスラッシュ(\)を入力しようとすると、代わりに « が入力される

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEAのエディタ画面、および内蔵のターミナルで \ (US配列の外付けキーボードで Alt + ) を入力すると、\ の代わりに « (左フレンチダブルクォート）が入力されてしまいます。
VSCode, Iterm2, Google Chromeなど、その他のアプリでは普通に \ が入力できるので困っています。

解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃったら教えていただけないでしょうか？

環境

- macOS Bigsur
- Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2020.02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ことえりのRomaji入力を使い続ける場合は `"¥"キー` で入力する文字を `\(バックスラッシュ)` へと変更する必要があるほか、Google日本語入力のAlphanumericを使うことでも解消できるようでした。

参考:
[[mac US配列] phpstormで \ (バックスラッシュ) が入力できない時の対処法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/gyuta/items/f4d7524ebe70d57f9dd2)

Answer (score 1):

まず、USキーボードで`\`が`Alt`キーとのコンビネーションというのが不思議です。

- システム環境設定の、キーボード→インプットソースの下にある、インプットソースをメニューバーに表示にチェックを入れ、
- USキーボードの時にインプットソースのツールバーから、キーボードビュワーを表示

で、そのまま、またはシフトキーを押した時に`\`を入力できるキーを探して見て下さい。

Comment: 試してみたところ、US配列のキーボードを接続しているにも関わらず日本語配列のキーボードビューワーが表示されてしまいました。